# limit the number of colors of an image to a specified number based on prodominant colors in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to process images in a way to limit the number of colors to a predetermined and specific number

I tried using this method

```py
from PIL import image

image= Image.open("input.png")
result = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=2)
result.save("saved.png")
```

for some reason it used to work but now doesn't work i'm pretty sure i didn't change anything

is there a fix or another method ?
thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED :
the problem is the color mode
to be able to use this function you need first to convert the color mode of the image to RGB like this :

```
image = image.convert('RGB')
```